# Issue with media queries and heights

Tags: css

I have two media queries like so:

```
@media(max-height: 1100px) and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

and this

```
@media(min-height: 750px) and (min-width: 1200px) {

}
```

My browser screen height is 779, What I am trying to do is apply css code if my screen height is 750px or less and width is 1200px or more. Also apply css code if my screen height is more than 750px and width is 1200px or more.

What am I doing wrong? Currently my `@media(max-height: 1100px) and (min-width: 1200px)` is overriding the `@media(max-height: 1100px) and (min-width: 1200px)` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, I believe you are missing a keyword or two... Also, if your desire is to have specific styling be applied on screens smaller than 750, you need to indicate a `max-height` of 750, not a `min-height`. (I did not change these below to reflect the max/min, only added in `screen and`).

```
@media screen and (max-height: 1100px) and (min-width: 1200px) {

}

@media screen and (min-height: 750px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
}
```